# Picasso in for loop loads only one image

Tags: android, android-asynctask, picasso

I'm using picasso to load several images which are parsed from a webservice... the problem is that I have mutliple items but only the last item is downloaded and loaded into the desired view... here's part of my code that handles the populating the items:

```
public void populate_jobs(ArrayList<RowItem> jobs)
{
    LinearLayout ll_parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_container);
    for(int i = 0;i < jobs.size();i+=3)
    {
        RowItem item_first = jobs.get(i);
        _items.add(item_first);
        RowItem item_second = null;
        RowItem item_third = null;
        if(jobs.size() > i+1)
        {
            item_second = jobs.get(i+1);
            _items.add(item_second);
        }
        if(jobs.size() > i+2)
        {
            item_third = jobs.get(i+2);
            _items.add(item_third);
        }
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_btn = new LayoutParams(convertToPx(100), convertToPx(100));
        lp_btn.setMargins(convertToPx(5), convertToPx(5), convertToPx(5), convertToPx(5));
        ImageButton btn_first = new ImageButton(this);
        btn_first.setLayoutParams(lp_btn);
        btn_first.setId(item_first.getId());

        //getImagesAsyncTask img_first = new getImagesAsyncTask(item_first.getImageSrc(), btn_first, this);
        //img_first.execute();
        Picasso.with(this)
        .load(item_first.getImageSrc().replace("~", URL_IAMGES))
        .fit()
        .into(btn_first, new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                String s = "asd";
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
            }
        });
        btn_first.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll.addView(btn_first);

        if(item_second != null)
        {
            ImageButton btn_second = new ImageButton(this);
            btn_second.setLayoutParams(lp_btn);
            btn_second.setId(item_second.getId());

            //getImagesAsyncTask img_second = new getImagesAsyncTask(item_second.getImageSrc(), btn_second, this);
            //img_second.execute();

            Picasso.with(this)
            .load(item_second.getImageSrc().replace("~", URL_IAMGES))
            .fit()
            .into(btn_second, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    String s = "asd";
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                }
            });
            btn_second.setOnClickListener(this);
            ll.addView(btn_second);
        }

        if(item_third != null)
        {
            ImageButton btn_third = new ImageButton(this);
            btn_third.setLayoutParams(lp_btn);
            btn_third.setId(item_third.getId());
            //getImagesAsyncTask img_second = new getImagesAsyncTask(item_third.getImageSrc(), btn_third, this);
            //img_second.execute();

            Picasso.with(this)
            .load(item_third.getImageSrc().replace("~", URL_IAMGES))
            .fit()
            .into(btn_third, new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    String s = "asd";
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                }
            }
                );
            btn_third.setOnClickListener(this);
            ll.addView(btn_third);
        }
        ll_parent.addView(ll);
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function of this for loop in the onPostExecute function of my asynctask which is responsible to fetch the json data from webservice. The content of the image source for all images are correct and can be accessed via browser, what could be the cause? thanks in advance

**EDIT:** as I've checked it seems it loads only 1 specific image, not the last one.

Comment: please post full code

Comment: +1. You need to post the complete code of the loop.

Comment: updated and added the whole function, it's been called in onPostExecute

Comment: Picasso is downloading images (how much about?) from urls and placing them in ImageButton's. Thats what you want. You do that creating layouts on the fly and adding three ImageButtons to every layout. Finally the layout gets attached to an existing layout. YOU should have told that!!. If all is done then how many buttons do you see with an image? All the same image? Please be more clear. How many times onSucces() is called? And how many onError()?

Comment: Please elaborate on `RowItem:getImageSrc().replace("~", URL_IAMGES))`. What is done by this function? `URL_IAMGES` will not be the same url for all images?

Comment: @greenapps yeah sorry about not being clear enough, it's around 30 images, each around 5kb, so it will end up with 30 buttons which only one will have an image, the onSuccess is called once as well and none for onError.

Comment: @greenapps the images are stored as ~/path/to/image.jpg so basically I'm replacing the "~" with the domain, the URL_IMAGES is a domain name of which the webservice is part of and no the result url is not the same for all images.

Comment: Ok. Please answer also how many images you see in the buttons. And better rename URL_IMAGES to BASE_URL_IMAGES.

Comment: Ok. Only one visible. Is it for the last button? First? Always the same?

Comment: From all the 30 images there's only 1 image loaded and it's always the same image and it's not the first nor the last one, it's the 20th image, the rest of the buttons are empty. About the renaming, yea that makes more sense.

Comment: Does the last row also have three buttons? Is the 20th the middle one of the three in a row?

Comment: it's 2 buttons, probably because the list is updated from another source, it was 30 few hours ago but now it's 32, but before when I was posting this question it was 30 and was 3 buttons at the bottom

Comment: Please do a test where you break out of the loop after nine urls done. Repeat with three. You could even try with only one button.

Comment: ok I've got something new and kinda strange, now my onError function is called, is there a way to get a error message?

Comment: I dont know. But put a log statement in it where you log i and the used url. `Picasso.with(this)` where `this' should be a Context. Is it the same as for the layouts?

Comment: yea the Context is the same, I've checked the img url and it's accessible through browser, everything seems to be normal but it triggers the onError, well atleast I know where it happens, somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56584/discussion-between-arash-moeen-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 1):

Url encode the url. Or replace the spaces with %20.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found it, the url contained spaces (thanks to the designer who created the images), so because of that picasso failed to download images which I didn't know they don't handle spaces in the url. anyway thanks to greenapps for his help.

Comment: Url encode the url. Or replace the spaces with %20.

Comment: yea already did that, thanks anyway for your step by step help